# PyCharm HTTPS Requests problem. Cannot see any requests results

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I have a problem with my PyCharm. It doesn't show me any requests results when I run my program.
The only thing I get is 'Process finished with exit code 0', but from what I saw from other guides it should show me an answer from site with speed.

simple code just to try requests:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
print(r.text)
```

I have requests library installed in my PyCharm settings

I am looking for you help, thanks

EDIT:

thats what I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bXm1.jpg)

thats what gets a guy from yt video guide with the same code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bODT.jpg)

As you can see, I am not getting any site response back :/

Comment: Do you run a script from PyCharm or use the integrated PyCharm python console? In any case, I wasn't able to replicate your issue.

Comment: I’ve run it just from pycharm

Comment: Have you tried to set `flush=True` attribute in the print function? Anyway, could you share your entire "run console" output? Thanks

Comment: Sure, will post it later here, thanks

Comment: Ive added edit with photos. Please take a look. thanks

Comment: One simple question is if you checked that your code is actually in the `main.py` *outside* site1/ folder.

Comment: oh ive checked it in my main .py outside of the site1 and yeah it worked, thanks. Do you maybe have an idea how to have it working in my main in site1 folder?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Right-click on the file and then "Run", or from the menu _Run_ select _Edit Configurations_.